# Can I get help identifying these models?

Tags: warhammer-40k

[image: These are the models I'd like identified]

These models were for sale on a site and I was wondering if anyone could help me identify what these models actually are before I decided to buy them.

Comment: "I was wondering if anyone could help me identify what these models actually are" Very poorly painted.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like two [Space Marine Commander](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Space-Marine-Commander-2015). That box can be used as either a Captain or a Lieutenant.

> This box set contains one multi-part plastic Space Marine Commander, including nine different weapon options, three variant heads and additional parts to further customise your model.

Left is a Captain with a combi-plasma and a power fist; Right is a Lieutenant with two power swords.

Comment: I'd guess they are ultramarines, as the most common blue and gold colored chapter, though the colors are a little dark for that chapter, more like Dark Hunters or Death Strike, though those use silver not gold for the accent. Could be Rainbow Warriors (though the shoulders wouldn't be outlined) or Imperial Paladins.

Comment: Probably Crimson Fists, given the dark blue armor and maroon power fist.

Comment: FWIW they could always be repainted, and the models are generic space marine, so you could turn them into your favorite faction w/ a little effort. And in fact, with the mediocre paint job on them, you probably would want to strip and repaint them.